# Why does KMS drmModeSetCrtc() fail with permission denied while running in X11 session?

Tags: c++, linux, xorg, video-card, modesetting

The title already implies the question, so what is blocking the execution from the sample program in this repo https://github.com/dvdhrm/docs/tree/master/drm-howto

It's a simple program showing KMS in action, so I downloaded it, compiled it and gave it a run. This was the output:

```
michael@lord:~/Downloads/docs/drm-howto$ sudo ./modeset
[sudo] password for michael: 
using card '/dev/dri/card0'
mode for connector 59 is 1920x1080
ignoring unused connector 68
ignoring unused connector 71
ignoring unused connector 75
cannot set CRTC for connector 59 (13): Permission denied
exiting
```

Also note that I have a running X11 session on my machine.
It seems X is already using the device `/dev/dri/card0` and blocks it for all other programs.

Here is my video card:

```
michael@lord:~/Downloads/docs/drm-howto$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
```

I have also added `i915.modeset=1` into `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and rebuilt it with `sudo update-initramfs -u` so it loads the driver from inside my kernel and not from the xorg side.

There is also the possibility that my driver doesn't support KMS but `lspci` has shown that I only have an internal intel graphics card installed. So I sticked with the xorg core display driver package which is installed by default from `xserver-xorg-core`.

None of these changes have taken affect.
The only way I can execute those examples is by killing the xorg session and let it run in tty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works as expected. Only DRM-Master is allowed to do modesetting, and there can only be one DRM-Master. X is already master.

You can become master using `drmSetMaster()` or implicitly by opening the the primary device node when there is no current master. (The example code becomes DRM-Master implicitly.)

See also the [drm-kms(7) man page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libdrm-dev/drm-kms.7.en.html).

Comment: In the example, where/how did you insert the call to `drmSetMaster()`? I'm trying to run under X.

Comment: @RyanMcClue You can't. You need to be master, but X is already master.

Comment: How would a game become master then? Is direct rendering by a video game from a x11/wayland session not a covered use case? oO

Comment: Great answer! I did not have to `stop` anything, I just switched to `tty1`, and during the switch I saw the video mode change and my monitor reinitialize. Then I could just run my master application and it worked (Raspberry OS Bookworm, Wayland).

Answer (score 1):

To execute any modeset application first disable the display server by

`sudo systemctl stop gdm3`

`sudo systemctl stop lightdm`

switch to command line through eighter `CTL + ALT + F1`, `CTL + ALT + F2`, `CTL + ALT + F3`

and execute
$ `sudo ./modeset`

Comment: In fact I just used `CTL + ALT + F2` and then ran the demo, it worked even without `sudo`. One thing is that it took me 10 seconds to switch back to X after the demo completed.